# Create a column name based on today date?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Have a df

```
a       
123     
41698
31864
38
235
```

how to create a column based on today's date. like this

```
a         08-01-20
123
41698
31864
38
235
```

Answer (score 2):

Create today datetime and convert to string by [`Timestamp.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.strftime.html), then create new column:

```
df[pd.to_datetime('today').strftime('%d-%m-%y')] = ''
#alternatives
#df[pd.Timestamp.now().strftime('%d-%m-%y')] = ''
#df[pd.Timestamp.today().strftime('%d-%m-%y')] = ''
print (df)
       a 08-01-20
0    123         
1  41698         
2  31864         
3     38         
4    235
```

Comment: I'm not sure that `datetime` being in scope (like `np`) is within `pd` is guaranteed so was going to suggest either what you've done with `Timestamp` or yet another alternative is ` pd.to_datetime('today')`...